# Junit and VSCode

Tags: java, junit, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get junit working in VS Code for my CSC142 class with the following code that was provided by the teacher.

[image]

But I can't seem to get it working.  I've installed junit 4.10 and set it as a permanent class path
[image]

I've installed Java Test Runner and also tried doing everything through command line.  I can't seem to get it to work.  I've followed three or four different install/usage tutorials online and every time I think i'm making progress and it never works.

If I click on the Java Test Runner on the left of VS Code and see my folder when I click on it there are no files under it.

[image]

When I try and run my code it says this.
[image]

I'm new to this and really want to wrap my head around it but i'm having some issues. Can someone point me in the right direction or help me out here?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you need to add the junit jar to your build path

Comment: How do I do that in VS Code?